# Simple ( or maybe not ) JSP test page

Tags: javascript

I have a test page that looks like this

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
```

```
<body>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
        <tr>
            <td width="50%">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="50%">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><H3>Service (True/False) check</H3></td>
            <td><H3>Response</H3></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><textarea id="trueFalseInput" onkeyup="trueFalseLookup()" style="margin-left:5px;width:300px;height:150px;" ></textarea></td>
            <td><textarea id="trueFalseResult" style="margin-left:5px;width:300px;height:150px;" ></textarea></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</body>
```

I import JQuery files and also my JS file.

testPage.js

```
        function trueFalseLookup()
    {
        var strToCheck = $('#trueFalseInput').val();

        $.getJSON( 'myService?text='+ strToCheck +'&type=exists'  ).
                success( trueFalseResponse ).
                error( function ()
        {
            $('#trueFalseResult').val("Error calling my service");
        });
    }

    function trueFalseResponse( data )
    {
        $('#trueFalseResult').val('');

        if( data.error )
        {
            $('#trueFalseResult').val('Error: ' + data.errorMessage );
        }
        else
        {
            for( var i=0; i < data.results.length; i++ )
            {
                $('#trueFalseResult').val($('#trueFalseResult').val() +  '[' + data.results[i].word + ']: '+ data.results[i].homophone + '\n');
            }
        }
    }
```

Everything works fine when I serve the JSP file from a server.
Is it possible to have this page opened by my brower on my local c:/ drive?
Can I use a HTTP url to import the JQuery files?  CAn I just paste my Javascript into the JSP file between Script tags?
How would I modify the ajax server calls to call "MyLocalHost" server?

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing the two different APIs provided for jQuery's Ajax calls.  Either:

```
// no failure API available, I believe, in this case.
$.getJSON( 'myService?text='+ strToCheck +'&type=exists', trueFalseResponse )
```

or

```
$.getJSON( 'myService?text='+ strToCheck +'&type=exists')
    .done(trueFalseResponse)
    .fail(/* ... */)
```

You can also do this with the basic `jQuery.ajax` call; and in that case, you might use the "success" property name.  But I think the second example would do what you need.

Comment: My code works ok if the page is served from a web server.  The problem I am having is $.getJSON( 'http://myserverDomainName/MyApp/myService?text='+ strToCheck +'&type=exists'  ). does not work.  Obviously I am not calling the server correctly but I can't figure out how to do it

Comment: Sorry, obviously I didn't read far enough.  You should be able to run the same from a local web server (Apache, IIS, or a more light-weight one.)  But many browsers' security model prohibits XHR calls to local files.  (There is a Chrome flag you can set to allow this, if you choose.)

Comment: Ok, so `.success` and `.error` are still there, just deprecated.  Even if they still work, you might want to consider replacing them with `.done` and `.fail` (or with a combined `.then`)